# Laravel Form Validator required_if

Tags: laravel, validation

I am facing a problem with **required_if** that, when i need to validate 
if **type_id = 3** external_id should be required.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'memberID'=> 'required', 
        'external_id'=>'required_if:type_id,3'
]);
```

error message will be

> The External id field is required when type id is 3.

validation working fine. But instead of ***type id is 3*** i need to display a description. like below shown.

> The External id field is required when type is category.

how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by create a custom validation message,

```
$customMessages = [
        'required_if' => 'The :attribute field is required when type is category'
    ];


$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'memberID'=> 'required', 
        'external_id'=>'required_if:type_id,3'
], $customMessages);
```